# How do I fix the error of NumberFormatException everytime I run the program?

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I have to create a love calculator object for my computer science class.
However, every time I compile and run the program I keep ending up with the error:

java.lang.NumberFormatException:

For input string: "70.78%" (in sun.misc.FloatingDecimal)

My code for the method:

```
public double calculate()
{
    double value1;
    double value2;
    double sqrt1;
    double sqrt2;
    double relationship;
    sqrt1 = Math.sqrt(name1.length());
    sqrt2 = Math.sqrt(name2.length());
    value1 = (Math.pow(name1.length(), 3)/(Math.random()+0.1))* sqrt1;
    value2 = (Math.pow(name2.length(), 3)/(Math.random()+0.1))* sqrt2;

    if(value1 > value2)
    {
        relationship = value2 / value1;
    }
    else
    {
        relationship = value1 / value2;
    }
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    return Double.parseDouble(nf.format(relationship));
}
```

I attempted to convert it to a float. I tried to separate it by declaring and initializing another double variable and returning that instead but they didn't work. I looked up solutions and most said to use a try and catch but I don't understand how that would work (since I just began the class and am a beginner).

How would I use a try and catch for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NumberFormat` is meant to create a human readable string. `70.78%` *isn't* a number. `70.78` is, but with the percent sign, it's a string. It seems like what you're trying to do is use the number formatting functionality to round the number. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java) has some suggestions for how to properly round a number and keep it as a number.

To answer your other question, the proper way to use a `try/catch` would be like this:

```
 double result;
 try{
   result = Double.parseDouble(nf.format(relationship));
 }catch(NumberFormatException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
   result = 0.0;
 }
 return result;
```

But the only thing that will do is cause your program to not crash and you'll always get `0.0` returned from the `calculate()` method. Instead you need to fix the *source* of the exception.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to round the number and keep it as a number, but also include the % sign. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: @immmjimmy No. A `double` cannot store a percent sign.

Comment: You'd need to return a `String` instead. A `double` is _only_ the number

Comment: So would it be possible to return result + "%"?
EDIT: I just saw your answer Chris

Answer (score 0):

As you see the exception stacktrace, the exception is caused by string `70.78%`. This is because it has a symbol where `Double.parseDouble()` is expecting a string in format of double value representation like `70.78`. If you are looking for an output like `70.78%` and if the value is correct, you may return `nf.format(relationship)` and change your return type of `calculate` to `String`.

### Update

The following values are valid to be parsed as double: `"1.2", "1", ".2", "0.2", "1.2D", "1."`, to say a valid number representation holdable by the datatype.

Comment: Changing it to String did work. When would a double/int/float not work in String?